# How to run keycloak quy.io image in Azure container instance

Tags: azure, docker-compose, yaml, containers

My keycloak image is running without any error in local docker container then I have push it to ACR and tried to run a container from there but its not working ...below you can see my compose file.
[image]

[image]

```
services:
  auth:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin 
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: 
      - start-dev 
      - --import-realm
    volumes:
      - /home/keycloak/realm.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json
```

I need to know that what are the special things I have to do when going to Azure container instance, because its running locally and I pushed the same image to the the ACR.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, you'll simply just have to map the properties to the ACI configuration. This applies to the image name, port,env vars and command.

```bash
az container create -g innerloop --name keycloak1 --image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest --command-line "start-dev --import-realm" --environment-variables 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN'='admin' 'KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD'='admin'
```

Where it does get a little more sticky is the volume you're mounting. Azure Container Instances will mount from [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files) or a [git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-gitrepo).

You'll need to put your json files in one of these two places and then provide the mount parameters.